# jquerymobile - problems with anchor navigation on onepage site

Tags: jquery, mobile, anchor

I'm new to jquery mobile and don't understand why basic anchor navigation doesn't work. It should be one page, displaying the content after loading (if I insert data-role=page the content is hidden - however navigation doesn't work at all).
The anchor link to the panel works, but not the navigation links to the anchors !?

Any hint!?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
        <h2>Panel Header</h2>
          <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#acura">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="#audi">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bmw">BMW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cadillac">Cadillac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ferrari">Ferrari</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /navbar -->

    <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key or by swiping.</p>
  </div> <!-- /panel -->

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
        <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>

            <div id="acura" >
                <h1>Acura</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>

                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="audi"  >
                <h1>Audi</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>

                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="bmw"  >
                <h1>BMW</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>

                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="cadillac" >
                <h1>Cadillac</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>

                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>  

            <div id="ferrari" data-role="page">
                <h1>Ferrari</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>

                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>  
  </div><!-- /main -->

  <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 

</div> <!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found out the anchor link from the panel to the page works with data-ajax="false"!!

Comment: Maybe [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) can be useful for you? You can use it [without auto scrolling](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html) but keeping the URL hashes and their animations.